# Setting index of select elements across a class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a form that has various select elements like this

```
<select class="nace">
<option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
<option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

I am trying to write a jQuery snippet that will change the selection of all these selects of the class "nace", so the slected values are all in unison. But I am struggling a bit with the functionality.
So far I have an event bound to a the changes on selects but cant quite get it right. Can anyone help me?

```
    $('.nace').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('.nace option:selected="selected"' ).each(function(){
            $(this+' option[value='+$(this).value+']').attr('selected', 'selected');

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have said just this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.nace').change(function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $('.nace' ).val(selected);
    });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic, thankyou ever so much, I think I was almost there but was trying to overcomplicate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**JAVACSRIPT**

```
$('.nace').change(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $('.nace' ).each(function(){
        $(this).val(selected);
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<select class="nace">
    <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<select class="nace">
    <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>

<select class="nace">
    <option value="no" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Example here
http://jsfiddle.net/FwYmf/

Comment: +1 - Just to let you know that you don't need the '.each'. jQuery will go through all of the matching elements. Just applying `$('.nace').val(selected)` will set them all to the same value :)

Comment: You don't need the `each`. Every element in the set will be affected if you just use `$('.nace').val(...);`

Comment: Correct. I just re looked at it and turns out you don't need the .each

Answer (score 1):

This should be sufficient:

```
var $nace = $('.nace').change(function() {
    $nace.val($(this).val());
    // or (but not necessary) $nace.not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

OT: If your `select` field has only two options, consider using radio buttons.